# "telic" vs. "atelic" sentence

Tags: aspect

*John stopped drinking beer.*

In one grammar book there is something written about this sentence.

> "If the clause can be added to *stop* in the form of an *ing*-clause, the sentence is atelic."

I am not able to find out this sentence atelic given the fact I have read about the differences between atelic and telic verbs.

> "The telicity is the property of a verb or verb phrase that presents an action or event as being complete in some sense".

The exemplary sentence semantically suggests that John quit drinking beer once and for all. It is a completed decision.

So why atelic sentence? Is it so because "stop" is not action verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your grammar book means, but has expressed rather confusingly, is something like this:

> If an independent clause **C** can be cast as gerund complement to the verb *STOP*, then **C** is an atelic clause.

In your example, the "sentence" being tested for telicity—clause **C**—is not the entire sentence *John stopped drinking beer* but its complement clause *[<sub>subj</sub>John] drinking beer* in its canonical form before recasting as a gerund clause:

> *John drank beer* **or** *John was drinking beer*.

These two clauses are, indeed, atelic: *drink* is used here as an [activity](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) verb. This use contrasts with *drink* used as a telic **accomplishment** verb with the sense "drink completely".

> *John drank six beers.*

My favorite test for telicity is the *in/for T* contrast, where *T* is a measured timespan like *a week* or *ten minutes*. If the clause accommodates a temporal adjunct of the form ***in** T*, then it is telic, but if it only accommodates temporal adjuncts of the form ***for** T* then it is atelic.

> <sup>∗</sup> *John drank beer **in** an hour.*
> <sup>ok</sup>*John drank beer **for** an hour.*
>
> <sup>ok</sup>*John drank six beers **in** an hour.*
> <sup>∗</sup> *John drank six beers **for** an hour.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just one question. Is it possible to say "John was stopping drinking beer" in order to express that John made in the past many attempts to definitely give up drinking beer?

Comment: @bart-leby You *could*, but I don't think anybody *would*: they'd say something like *John kept trying to stop drinking beer*.